# Flickr photo uploading

Tags: c#, flickr

I have found the following code from [here](http://amitpatelit.com/2013/01/08/upload-photo-in-flickr-by-asp-net-code/)

```
f = new Flickr(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"],
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shardSecret"]);
OAuthRequestToken requestToken = f.OAuthGetRequestToken("oob");
string url = f.OAuthCalculateAuthorizationUrl(requestToken.Token, AuthLevel.Write);
```

and

```
OAuthRequestToken requestToken = f.OAuthGetRequestToken("oob");
var accessToken = f.OAuthGetAccessToken(requestToken, VerifierTextBox.Text);
```

I was able to get the API key and shared secret.

What is the use of the parameter `oob` ?

I'm trying to use this code in a desktop application.

Are there any good sample codes for desktop applications?